# Spring MVC java based configuration without xml not working

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to create sample spring MVC application with java based configuration with annotation so I am not using any XML file for configuration.

I have below Controller, Dispatcher servlet initializer class.

My JSP file is `home.jsp` which is present inside `WEB-INF/view` folder.  Kindly help.

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showHome(Model model) {

        return "home";
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.luv2code.springsecurity")
public class DemoAppConfig {

    // define a bean for ViewResolver

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

}

public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{DemoAppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working? Is there any error you are getting? Please post some more details so that people can understand and help.

Comment: Try adding `viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);` after instantiating view resolver.